# How can I create this query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this MySQL Query here:

```
SELECT
   COUNT(*) ReleasePerMonth,
   d.name as DevGroup_REGION 
FROM
   release_summary r 
   inner join
      gti_server_info g 
      on r.gti_server_id = g.gti_server_id 
   inner join
      dev_group d 
      on d.dev_group_id = g.dev_group_id 
WHERE
   r.testingFinishedOn_timestamp >= '2020-05-01 00:00:00' 
   AND r.testingFinishedOn_timestamp <= '2020-05-31 00:00:00' 
   AND r.test_type != 14 
GROUP BY
   d.name ;
```

Now, I want this to run for every month. That is,

```
   r.testingFinishedOn_timestamp >= '2019-01-01 00:00:00' 
   AND r.testingFinishedOn_timestamp <= '2019-01-31 00:00:00'
```

and

```
   r.testingFinishedOn_timestamp >= '2019-05-02 00:00:00' 
   AND r.testingFinishedOn_timestamp <= '2019-02-31 00:00:00'
```

Till end of year. Currently, I am doing this manually. Is there any way I can do it in an automated manner?

Clarification:

I'd want 12 seperate tables for each of the 12 months.

Comment: Do you want 1) get the data for all 12 months in one query? execute 12 separate queries?

Comment: There's a bug in your query: you're using `<=` with an **incorrect inclusive upperbound** instead of `<` with an exclusive upper-bound (so you're missing an entire day's worth of data!). You can also omit the time components for brevity, so change your `WHERE` to this: `r.testingFinishedOn_timestamp >= '2020-05-01' AND r.testingFinishedOn_timestamp < '2019-06-01'`.

Comment: @Akina, I'd want 12 seperate tables for each of the 12 months.

Comment: You may execute 12 different queries iterating over months in client code and get 12 separate rowsets. You may use one stored procedure or multi-query and get one rowset pack which consists from 12 separate rowsets, then iterate over them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT
   YEAR(r.testingFinishedOn_timestamp) year,
MONTH(r.testingFinishedOn_timestamp) month,
   COUNT(*) ReleasePerMonth,
   d.name as DevGroup_REGION 
FROM
   release_summary r 
   inner join
      gti_server_info g 
      on r.gti_server_id = g.gti_server_id 
   inner join
      dev_group d 
      on d.dev_group_id = g.dev_group_id 
WHERE
   r.test_type != 14 
GROUP BY
   YEAR(r.testingFinishedOn_timestamp),
   MONTH(r.testingFinishedOn_timestamp),
   d.name
ORDER BY year, month;
```

Comment: Why not use the aliases in your `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Hey, this seems to work, but this returns only for a single month. I want this produced table for each of the 12 months. This only returns it for a single month.

Comment: You can't. It would throw an error. But you could put your main select clause in a subquery and define a named column that way.

Comment: I simply forgot to tidy up your `WHERE` clause. I have done that now. Please check again.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below query - using `last_day()`

```
SELECT year(r.testingFinishedOn_timestamp),month(r.testingFinishedOn_timestamp),
   COUNT(*) ReleasePerMonth
    
FROM
   release_summary r 
   inner join
      gti_server_info g 
      on r.gti_server_id = g.gti_server_id 
   inner join
      dev_group d 
      on d.dev_group_id = g.dev_group_id 
WHERE
   r.testingFinishedOn_timestamp >= date_add(date_add(LAST_DAY(now()),interval 1 DAY),interval -12 MONTH) 
   AND r.testingFinishedOn_timestamp <= LAST_DAY(now()) 
   AND r.test_type != 14 
GROUP BY
   year(r.testingFinishedOn_timestamp),month(r.testingFinishedOn_timestamp) ;
```

Comment: @Akina, can you please check here - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=bd70ae0f88b1ceaf0afe70b3c0e53b87

Comment: Sorry, wasn't paying attention precisely.

Comment: @Akina, no issues - :)

Comment: @Fahmi, I was looking for a query that would produce 12 different tables,1 for each month with the data same as the one returned by my query above.

Comment: @JohnDoe, I've updated the query adding group by year(r.testingFinishedOn_timestamp), month(r.testingFinishedOn_timestamp) - you can check now if it satisfies your requirement or not

Comment: @Fahmi, I am not sure why this query doesn't generate exact data as my query above. This groups data according to the `DevGroup_REGION` but I'd want data to be ordered by `month` for all years/2019.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to query data for the entire year and group by **MONTH**(testingFinishedOn_timestamp).

I added the query below but it's not tested:

```
SELECT
   MONTH(r.testingFinishedOn_timestamp) ReleaseMonth,
   COUNT(*) ReleasePerMonth,
   d.name as DevGroup_REGION 
FROM
   release_summary r 
   inner join
      gti_server_info g 
      on r.gti_server_id = g.gti_server_id 
   inner join
      dev_group d 
      on d.dev_group_id = g.dev_group_id 
WHERE
   r.testingFinishedOn_timestamp >= '2020-01-01 00:00:00' 
   AND r.testingFinishedOn_timestamp < '2021-01-01 00:00:00' 
   AND r.test_type != 14 
GROUP BY
   d.name, MONTH(r.testingFinishedOn_timestamp);
ORDER BY
  MONTH(r.testingFinishedOn_timestamp), d.name
```

Based on the [documentation](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-month/) available, MONTH() function returns the number of the month, for instance for January returns 1.
If you want to have the name of the month you case use MONTHNAME() function instead of Month().